# Why low audio frequencies seem to detune after an intense workout?

Tags: neuroscience, hearing

After a specially intense workout (biking, running...), listening to music with headphones, I hear the music pitch has dropped slightly. What I find odd is that not all parts of the sound are detuned, just the low frequencies.

It happens to me every time I push the workout a bit harder than normal. I can hear the bass out of tune with the rest of the instruments. After a couple of minutes of rest, my hearing is back to normal.

What could be causing this effect?

Comment: Hi hso, welcome to stack exchange.  Could you possibly edit your question to be less anecdotal and apply more general to human cognition and neuroscience?  I will answer anecdotally in my next comment.

Comment: This might be an effect of sound-conducting fluids in the ear canal.